# Statistical tests vs model selection

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, model-selection

I'm analyzing health data with case reports which contain patient information including diagnosis, age, sex, location etc. The sample sizes are not very large.

I want to explore the data for relationships between the variables, for example:
-Is there a higher frequency of diagnosis A among females than males
-Is there a higher frequency of diagnosis B among children than adults
-Does location X have a higher frequency of diagnosis A than location Y

-Is it better to use a statistical test or to fit models including/excluding the category and compare goodness-of-fit?

Comment: Please, would you mind giving just one specific example with this goodness of fit approach for the mentioned variables of your dataset.

Comment: An example of a goodness of fit approach would be to fit a model for cases ~ time, and cases ~ time + sex, and to see if including the variable "sex" in the model yields a better fit by a metric such as AIC. I am trying to understand if this is a better approach than a statistical test such as ANOVA?

Comment: If the location is a categorical variable like all the rest, there is no room for the ANOVA or regression-type models. Because there are no numeric variables here. What we deal with here is a multidimensional "contingency table". If you limit your "models" to one-factor ones, it's going to be either chi-squared or Fisher's exact test in most cases (not ANOVA for which you need to have a numeric dependent variable, which the diagnosis is not). That's why I wanted to see if you have a plan or an idea how to use this AIC/BIC, whatever, for contingency tables' tests.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'm confused about using the chi-squared test as you recommended because chi-squared tells me if my categorical variables are independent/not. So the chi-squared tells me that patient age and diagnosis are not independent from each other, but doesn't tell me if the frequency of a particular diagnosis is higher in one age group than another. Is there a way around this using the methods you suggest? (That is why I had in mind to use a model so I have an actual predicted frequency). (Because it is case count data I can't use tests that compare mean/median etc.)

Comment: Actually this test on independence does says whether "there is a higher frequency of diagnosis A among females than males, whether there is a higher frequency of diagnosis B among children than adults, whether location X has a higher frequency of diagnosis A than location Y". The lack of independence means that one of the two values of one category increases the odds of having another particular value from the 2nd category. Exactly what you seem to want.

Comment: I did some searching on this and found the binomial test. How do I know if it makes more sense to use the chi-squared to test for independence of categories or the binomial test to check if the incidences (cases/capita) are different between groups? For example, I used chi-squared to see if diagnosis and age are independent and it showed they are not. Then I used the binomial test to see if the incidence in children is higher than the incidence in adults and it told me the proportions are not the same. These two tests are in agreement, but are they both equally valid approaches? (thanks :) )

Comment: The common chi-square test we are talking about is a *two-way* test; it is for contingency tables. While the binomial test is a *one-way* test for **one** binary category. It can be used if you take, for instance, the category of disease (yes/no) and only children (not as a category, just the filter) and try to establish if your data support a hypothesis that the probability of this disease in the pediatric population is a predefined value *p*.